# Sharing object from LineCallbackHandler to ExecutionCOntext

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, chunks

I have a csv file with one line on the top considered as the header.
My reader configuration is as following :

```
FlatFileItemReader<EncCreditEntrepIndDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<EncCreditEntrepIndDTO>()
            .strict(false)
            .resource(resource)
            .linesToSkip(1)
            .skippedLinesCallback(headerHandler)
            .lineMapper(mapper)
            .saveState(false)
            .build();
    return reader;
```

This is my LineCallbackHandler :

```
public class HeaderHandler implements LineCallbackHandler {


@Override
public void handleLine(String line) {
    AtomicReference<StepHeader> headerLine = new AtomicReference<>();
    processLine(line, headerLine);

}
```

After processing the headerline, i want to save it in the execution context to use it later in some steps .
I tried implementing StepListener and then StepExecutionListener and retrieve the actual context. It is always equals to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried implementing StepListener and then StepExecutionListener and retrieve the actual context. It is always equals to null

Implementing `StepExecutionListener` should work if you register your callback handler as a listener in the step:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<EncCreditEntrepIndDTO> itemReader(HeaderHandler headerHandler) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<EncCreditEntrepIndDTO>()
            // ...
            .skippedLinesCallback(headerHandler)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, HeaderHandler headerHandler) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<EncCreditEntrepIndDTO, EncCreditEntrepIndDTO>chunk(5)
            .reader(itemReader(headerHandler))
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .listener(headerHandler)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The problem is : when in parse the header with callBackHandler i want to put it in the job context so the reader of the current step can retrieve some information from that header to do some specific process. It does not work ... The only solution i found is to add a tasklet to parse the header separately and put it in the job context (the header has different model from the csv lines)